# Need to get a value of assigned variable in pl/sql

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql

This is my query.

```
declare  
    a varchar2(1) := 'A';  
    b varchar2(1);  
begin  
   b := a;  
   someFunction(b) --- I need this function to return a (as it is the assigned        
                       variable to b, and not value 'A' Is it possible through  
                       inbuild oracle function?  
end;
```

Comment: you mean instead of variable value it should return variable name ? Is it ? :s

Comment: Yes, sort of tricky requirement. One of my colleague said he has used it in distant past but dont seem to remember it.

Comment: function to return a  as variable or 'a'  as string constant? I have put the same question long time before. but it did not resolved.

Comment: You may share your actual requirement so that we may think about alternative.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have a table which contains filed_name, field_value, field_position, field_length, field_msgtype.  Now, I have function with argumets as these fields...for e.g, table has field with name 'A','B','C' and the function has arguments with the same name. I need to build a string with all the function arguments using the postion and length from the table above mentioned.

Comment: the problem you described above looks like that you want to have a pointer to a variable. As far as I know this is not possible in PL/SQL!

Comment: What alternative you used for your requirement @ShravanYadav ?

Comment: I still don't quite follow what you're trying to do. Can you edit your question to add a fuller explanation and an example of the data and what you want to pass and return? You've made your code snippet so generic it's hard to see what the intent is.

Comment: I think TopicStarter has a table with some columns, and that he needs to retieve data from that table. There is a column `Name` with entry `A`, `B`, `C` etc. And the values from column `Value` for example need to be put in a variable that can be send to a function.

Comment: I think you need a cursor that feches the column values in a record. Have a look about `cursors` and `records`. I think that might be something you are looking for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL doesn't have reference semantics for variables so there is no (build-in) way to do what you're asking (PL/SQL is not C nor Java). Depending what you really need to do you might be able to work-around that e.g. with a [dynamic PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115) or [cursor variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00605).

Essentially you're having a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), please explain your real problem.

The assigment in your example:

```
b := a;
```

is a deep copy. At this point the variables have the same value but they are still independent so

```
a := 'B'
```

Doesn't change the value of variable `b`.